# WPF: Data Binding A Slider Value To A ToolTip Content String In XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, slider, tooltip

In a C# based WPF UserControl, I have a set of Sliders to adjust the Red,Green and Blue values of a Color element; essentially the UserControl is a color picker.  I have a combination of XAML and C# code behind for the ToolTipOpening Event Handler that allows me to set the individual integer value representing the Color component property value.  So, if I have the slider positioned for adjusting the amount of Red in the color in the middle of the Slider,  the ToolTip will display "Red: 125", as each Color component property value can range from 0 to 255.  The code fragments below for both the XAML and C# work as expected:

**XAML:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="CustomColorPicker.ColorPickerUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Name="colorPicker">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="175" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Right">Red:</Label>
        <Slider Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Name="sliderRed" Minimum="0" Maximum="255"
                Margin="{Binding ElementName=colorPicker, Path=Padding}"
                Value="{Binding ElementName=colorPicker, Path=Red}" 
                ToolTipOpening="OnColorSliderToolTipOpening" 
                ToolTip="Red: 0" />

        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Green:</Label>
        <Slider Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="sliderGreen" Minimum="0" Maximum="255"
                Margin="{Binding ElementName=colorPicker, Path=Padding}"
                Value="{Binding ElementName=colorPicker, Path=Green}" 
                ToolTipOpening="OnColorSliderToolTipOpening" ToolTip="Green: 0" />

        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Blue:</Label>
        <Slider Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Name="sliderBlue" Minimum="0" Maximum="255"
                Margin="{Binding ElementName=colorPicker, Path=Padding}"
                Value="{Binding ElementName=colorPicker, Path=Blue}" 
                ToolTipOpening="OnColorSliderToolTipOpening" ToolTip="Blue: 0" />

        <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="3"
                   Margin="{Binding ElementName=colorPicker, Path=Padding}"
                   Width="85" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding ElementName=colorPicker, Path=Color}" />
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>    
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**C#:**

```
    private void OnColorSliderToolTipOpening(object sender, ToolTipEventArgs e)
    {
        Slider slider = (Slider) sender;

        string colorName = "N/A";
        int colorValue = 0;

        if (slider.Name == "sliderRed")
        {
            colorName = "Red";
            colorValue = (int) Color.R;                
        }

        else if (slider.Name == "sliderGreen")
        {
            colorName = "Green";
            colorValue = (int) Color.G;
        }

        else if (slider.Name == "sliderBlue")
        {
            colorName = "Blue";
            colorValue = (int) Color.B;
        }

        string colorTip =
        string.Format("{0}: {1}", colorName, colorValue.ToString());

        slider.ToolTip = colorTip;

        return;
    }
```

Is there a way to eliminate the code behind and set the ToolTip contents to display the  same string using the ***ToolTip.Content*** and ***ToolTip.ContentStringFormat*** properties in XAML only, allowing for the elimination of the ToolTipOpening event handler in the code behind in C#?  I've tried the following XAML using DataBinding to format the content string of the Slider's ToolTip:

**XAML:**

```
    <Slider Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Name="sliderBlue" Minimum="0" Maximum="255"
            Margin="{Binding ElementName=colorPicker, Path=Padding}"
            Value="{Binding ElementName=colorPicker, Path=Blue}">
        <Slider.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip
                Content="{Binding ElementName=colorPicker, Path=Blue}"
                ContentStringFormat="{}Blue: {0}" />
        </Slider.ToolTip>
    </Slider>
```

and the ToolTip Popup display comes up empty:

[image: *Slider with Empty ToolTip using XAML only*]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Binding per `ElementName` just like `RelativeSource` with `FindAncestor` isn't in scope because `ToolTip` is a `Popup` which isn't part of the VisualTree (it creates its own). But you can use the [ToolTip.PlacementTarget Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltip.placementtarget.aspx) to get the `Slider` control and catch the Value.

```
<Slider.ToolTip>
    <ToolTip Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                               Path=PlacementTarget.Value}"
             ContentStringFormat="Blue: {0:0}" />
</Slider.ToolTip>
```

Please note the additional `:0` in `ContentStringFormat="Blue: {0:0}"` to round the Value.