# How to change the "information" over a WPF Slider?

Tags: wpf, slider

My Slider in Wpf Looks like:

```
<Slider Margin="462,10,10,0" x:Name="SliderAllMethodsCountToGetData" 
        AutoToolTipPlacement="TopLeft" 
        Height="28" VerticalAlignment="Top" Maximum="25" 
        SmallChange="1" IsMoveToPointEnabled="True" 
        ToolTip="Seconds" AllowDrop="True" Interval="1" 
        SelectionStart="1" SelectionEnd="10" 
        IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" TickFrequency="1"/>
```

[image]

but i want it look like

[image]

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF: Data Bindining A Slider Value To A ToolTip Content String In XAML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577521/wpf-data-bindining-a-slider-value-to-a-tooltip-content-string-in-xaml)